# Sort snapshot.data from firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I am getting data via a FutureBuilder and I want to sort it based on the creationTime but I always get as a return null

Code:

```
        print(snapshot.data['negotiationValues'].sort((a, b) {
                  return ((a['createdAt'] as Timestamp)
                      .compareTo(b['createdAt'] as Timestamp));
                }));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by making use of

```
snapshot.data['negotiationValues'].reversed.toList();
```